# How can I use Android 4.1 with my Mac OS X 10.5?

Tags: macos, macbook, file-transfer

I cannot connect my Galaxy Note 2 (running Android 4.1 Jelly Bean at the moment) to my Macbook (running OS X 10.5.8).
Can someone please give me some advise as I tried Android File Transfer and this doesn't work.  Airdroid is ok, but transfers music one song at a time and only via WiFi.  I would like to connect my USB to my Mac and transfer this way if possible (I don't always have an internet or 3G connection, etc)

Please help me find a solution, IF there is one.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a phone focused solution, but I've had great luck with transferring files with a web based file transfer and management software called [airdroid](http://www.airdroid.com/). Its a lot more reliable than samsung's own kies software (which I find a horror) and works through a web browser so on the computer side, its platform independant.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup and the only way I could get Android File Transfer to work was to first uninstall Kies. I only used Kies to transfer contacts once, so I don't miss it at all.
Let me know if uninstalling Kies works for you.